# What would be a better form for a question like, "Is there scientific evidence for .... "?

Tags: discussion

An example:

Q: Is there scientific evidence for dogs being fish?

A: Yes. As evidence is a functional category, if I claim that dogs are fish as both are eukaryotes, Opisthokontas, bilaterias, deuterostomes, chordates, craniatas, vertebrates and gnathostomatas, then there is scientific evidence for dogs being fish.

What would be a better form for this question?

Comment: The example question can be better modified to 'Is there scientific evidence for dogs being related to fish?' since the evidence comparison is between Carnivora and Gnathostomata rather than 'Is there scientific evidence for dogs being fish?' or 'Is there scientific evidence for fish being dogs?'

Answer (score 2):

Just ask if dogs are fish.

Answers on this site default to providing the best evidence available on the topic.

Comment: This. I can't count how many questions can I edited by asking the direct ...question, instead of a convoluted, "could x be true" or "what is the evidence that x is true..."